# MongoDB dynamic variables in MapReduce

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mapreduce

I have node.js router for mongodb mapreduce:

```
app.get('/api/facets/:collection/:groupby', function(req, res) {
    var collection = db.collection(req.params.collection);
    var groupby = req.params.groupby;
    var map = function() {
      if (!this.region) {
        return;
      }
      for (index in this.region) {
        emit(this.region[index], 1);
      }
    }
    var reduce = function(previous, current) {
      var count = 0;

      for (index in current) {
        count += current[index];
      }
      return count;
    }
    var options = {out: groupby + '_facets'};
    collection.mapReduce(map, reduce, options, function (err, collection) {
    collection.find(function (err, cursor) {
        cursor.toArray(function (err, results) {
                res.send(results);
            });            
    })
    })
});
```

This works good. But I want to use my `groupby` param. When I try to do something like this:

```
  var map = function() {
    if (!this[groupby]) {
            return;
        }
    for (index in this[groupby]) {
            emit(this[groupby][index], 1);
        }
  }
```

I receive `TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined`. Is there any way to create such dynamic mapreduce function?

Thanks.

**Edited:**

Wow! I do it myself. Just pass `scope` param to mapreduce argument like so `scope:{keys: groupby}` and then I was able to do `var key = this[keys]` inside map function and use `key` variable instead `this.region`. Great!

Comment: You should post and accept your answer.

Comment: @generalhenry Agreed it will help others in future, please post answer and accept OP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow! I solved it myself. I just passed a scope param to the mapreduce argument.

```
scope:{keys: groupby}
```

Then I was able to do

```
var key = this[keys]
```

inside map function and use key variable instead of this.region. Great!